# What is the name of this stochastic process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, terminology, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

I encounter a problem in practical application but don't know where to start.

Suppose there is a time-series dataset $X_i(t_{i,j})$ of $n$ series, for $i = 1, 2, \dots, n$. For each time series $i$, we have a series of observations at different times $t_{i,j}$, $j = 1, 2, \dots, m_i$, where $(t_{i,j+1} - t_{i,j})$ is a random variable, i.e. not a constant.

The closest one that comes to my mind is the non-homogeneous Poisson process and its extension, but I can't pin this stochastic modeling problem to any specific stochastic process. Is it perhaps the jump process?

Comment: If $t_{ij}$ is a random variable then $X_i(t_{ij})$ is a random variable for every $i$ and $j$. It is a time-discrete random process (either in $i$ or in $j$). That's it. Why you need a name? You should give precise definitinons, not throwing around names.